# Why does ioctl with SIOCGIFCONF occasionally execute slowly?

Tags: java, linux, linux-kernel, network-programming, system-calls

When I used JDK8 on Linux, I found that the `java.net.NetworkInterface#getNetworkInterfaces` method occasionally took several seconds to return, so I wrote the following Java program to try to reproduce the problem:

```java
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class NetworkTest {

    private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
                long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                long cost = endTime - startTime;
                if (cost > 200) {
                    System.out.println("time: " + LocalDateTime.now().format(DATE_TIME_FORMATTER) + ", cost: " + cost + "ms");
                }
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

At the same time, I used `strace` to trace the program and found that ioctl with SIOCGIFCONF occasionally executed slowly. The following is the captured log that took a long time.

Java output:

```
time: 2023-12-26 20:51:22.453, cost: 1971ms
```

`strace` output:

```
20:51:20.482408 socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 8
20:51:20.482448 ioctl(8, SIOCGIFCONF, {1000 -> 80, NULL}) = 0
20:51:21.450974 ioctl(8, SIOCGIFCONF, {80, {{"lo", {AF_INET, inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}}, {"eth0", {AF_INET, inet_addr("10.0.16.15")}}}}) = 0
20:51:22.452894 ioctl(8, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="lo", ifr_flags=IFF_UP|IFF_LOOPBACK|IFF_RUNNING}) = 0
20:51:22.452960 ioctl(8, SIOCGIFNETMASK, {ifr_name="lo", ifr_netmask={AF_INET, inet_addr("255.0.0.0")}}) = 0
20:51:22.453023 ioctl(8, SIOCGIFINDEX, {ifr_name="lo", ifr_index=1}) = 0
20:51:22.453060 ioctl(8, SIOCGIFFLAGS, {ifr_name="eth0", ifr_flags=IFF_UP|IFF_BROADCAST|IFF_RUNNING|IFF_MULTICAST}) = 0
20:51:22.453093 ioctl(8, SIOCGIFBRDADDR, {ifr_name="eth0", ifr_broadaddr={AF_INET, inet_addr("10.0.16.15")}}) = 0
20:51:22.453127 ioctl(8, SIOCGIFNETMASK, {ifr_name="eth0", ifr_netmask={AF_INET, inet_addr("255.255.255.255")}}) = 0
20:51:22.453161 ioctl(8, SIOCGIFINDEX, {ifr_name="eth0", ifr_index=128}) = 0
20:51:22.453199 close(8)                = 0
20:51:22.453242 socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 8
20:51:22.453297 open("/proc/net/if_inet6", O_RDONLY) = 9
20:51:22.453360 fstat(9, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
20:51:22.453410 mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7cd648e000
20:51:22.453448 read(9, "fe80000000000000b8cef600741e59e0"..., 1024) = 108
20:51:22.453517 read(9, "", 1024)       = 0
20:51:22.453552 read(9, "", 1024)       = 0
20:51:22.453590 close(9)                = 0
20:51:22.453646 munmap(0x7f7cd648e000, 4096) = 0
20:51:22.453684 close(8)                = 0
20:51:22.453991 write(1, "time: 2023-12-26 20:51:22.453, c"..., 41) = 41
20:51:22.454055 write(1, "\n", 1)       = 1
```

From the above output, we can observe that ioctl with SIOCGIFCONF takes a long time twice. What is the possible reason? How can I continue to troubleshoot the cause?

**Reference:**
[java.net.NetworkInterface#getAll](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk8u/blob/master/jdk/src/solaris/native/java/net/NetworkInterface.c#L423-L479)

###### Update

I tried to use ftrace and systemtap to further troubleshoot, but because my Linux system is customized by the company, the above tools do not take effect (lack of relevant debug info). Are there any other troubleshooting ideas?

If I run the above NetworkTest for a long time, I can observe that slow requests occur at intervals of half an hour, but I don't know the reason.

```
time: 2024-01-03 11:51:20.459, cost: 769ms
time: 2024-01-03 11:51:22.458, cost: 999ms
time: 2024-01-03 12:21:21.451, cost: 550ms
time: 2024-01-03 12:51:21.453, cost: 558ms
time: 2024-01-03 13:06:20.456, cost: 780ms
time: 2024-01-03 13:06:23.453, cost: 1995ms
time: 2024-01-03 13:21:19.459, cost: 786ms
time: 2024-01-03 13:21:21.453, cost: 994ms
time: 2024-01-03 13:36:20.452, cost: 777ms
time: 2024-01-03 13:51:20.457, cost: 777ms
time: 2024-01-03 13:51:23.459, cost: 1002ms
time: 2024-01-03 14:06:20.458, cost: 775ms
time: 2024-01-03 14:06:22.458, cost: 1000ms
time: 2024-01-03 14:21:19.450, cost: 755ms
time: 2024-01-03 14:21:22.453, cost: 1002ms
time: 2024-01-03 14:36:20.451, cost: 777ms
time: 2024-01-03 14:51:22.452, cost: 1754ms
time: 2024-01-03 14:51:24.458, cost: 1006ms
time: 2024-01-03 15:06:21.454, cost: 1743ms
time: 2024-01-03 15:06:23.458, cost: 1004ms
time: 2024-01-03 15:21:21.456, cost: 728ms
time: 2024-01-03 15:21:23.458, cost: 1001ms
time: 2024-01-03 15:36:21.458, cost: 727ms
time: 2024-01-03 15:36:25.453, cost: 1994ms
time: 2024-01-03 15:51:22.460, cost: 732ms
time: 2024-01-03 15:51:25.452, cost: 1992ms
time: 2024-01-03 16:06:21.455, cost: 733ms
time: 2024-01-03 16:06:23.456, cost: 1001ms
time: 2024-01-03 16:21:22.454, cost: 727ms
time: 2024-01-03 16:36:21.458, cost: 735ms
time: 2024-01-03 16:36:24.451, cost: 1993ms
time: 2024-01-03 16:51:22.455, cost: 732ms
time: 2024-01-03 17:06:21.453, cost: 726ms
time: 2024-01-03 17:06:23.458, cost: 1005ms
time: 2024-01-03 17:21:21.455, cost: 726ms
time: 2024-01-03 17:36:20.458, cost: 732ms
time: 2024-01-03 17:36:22.457, cost: 999ms
time: 2024-01-03 17:51:21.456, cost: 730ms
time: 2024-01-03 18:06:21.451, cost: 724ms
time: 2024-01-03 18:21:21.457, cost: 731ms
time: 2024-01-03 18:36:20.457, cost: 725ms
time: 2024-01-03 18:36:23.455, cost: 1997ms
time: 2024-01-03 18:51:22.458, cost: 733ms
time: 2024-01-03 18:51:25.453, cost: 1994ms
time: 2024-01-03 19:06:23.451, cost: 1720ms
time: 2024-01-03 19:21:21.459, cost: 728ms
time: 2024-01-03 19:21:23.458, cost: 999ms
time: 2024-01-03 19:36:21.458, cost: 729ms
time: 2024-01-03 19:36:24.454, cost: 1995ms
time: 2024-01-03 19:51:23.451, cost: 1727ms
time: 2024-01-03 19:51:26.454, cost: 1002ms
time: 2024-01-03 20:06:23.455, cost: 729ms
time: 2024-01-03 20:21:22.453, cost: 1727ms
time: 2024-01-03 20:21:24.460, cost: 1006ms
```

Kernel version: 4.18.0-193.el8.#{company}.x86_64

Comment: A few ideas:
 1. You could write a C program that calls this ioctl and observe if you get the same behavior. You'll know if the problem is related to your Java code, or if it's a kernel issue.
 2. Calling an IOCTL leads to kernel processes to do the work for you. The kernel might not execute your processes right away, especially without an RT kernel. Is there a lot of CPU/network load on your system? You may want to increase the `nice` levels of your java app and the kernel processes, see if it gets better.
 3. The regularity of your stalls might be another periodic network process. Any?

Comment: I have one question. Why are you read network interfaces again and again?

Comment: @AnishB. Historical legacy code, inappropriate API design.

Comment: @Poison Oh! How do I test this locally?

Comment: @AnishB. Using the above Java program, you may not be able to reproduce this problem. I have not been able to reproduce this problem on other cloud hosts. It seems that this problem only exists on our company's host.

Answer (score 0):

`ioctl` is a system call for **device-specific** input/output operations... So there will be many scenarios where the execution of `ioctl` call can become slow, like:

**1-** Your system(host) has many network interfaces(logical/physical) on the system.
So `ioctl` needs to iterate through **each** interface to retrieve its configuration information.

**2-** There are network devices that are not functioning properly. Like broken or mis-configured network devices. 
So `ioctl` may experience delays or even timeouts while trying to retrieve information from these devices.

*Note that `NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()` is indeed a time-taking method, as it returns an enumeration of network interfaces on a machine.*

Comment: There are only two network interfaces, `lo` and `eth0`. Most of the time `NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()` only takes a few milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

After investigation, we confirmed that it was caused by [RTNL](https://lists.kernelnewbies.org/pipermail/kernelnewbies/2011-November/003979.html) lock contention and `NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()` was affected by `ethtool -S eth0`.

Reference:

- [linux/net/socket.c at v4.18 · torvalds/linux](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.18/net/socket.c#L983-L985)
- [linux/net/core/dev_ioctl.c at v4.18 · torvalds/linux](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.18/net/core/dev_ioctl.c#L427-L429)
- [rtnl mutex, the network stack big kernel lock](https://netdevconf.info/2.2/slides/westphal-rtnlmutex-talk.pdf)